# How can I fix dagger-hilt?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jentt.png)

I have tried three different projects however, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please edit your question, especially your title. The title looks like you want to fix dagger-hilt, but you want to fix your own code ;)
Also, please add your source code to the question and not just a screenshot. Screenshots cannot be easily searched.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please familiarize yourself with https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

hello world ependencies in your app/build.gradle file:

hello world